# Insert value in panda dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have data in an Excel sheet. I want to check one column value for a range and if that value lies in that range(5000-15000) then I want to insert value in another column(Correct or Flag).

I have three columns: City, rent, status.

I have tried append and insert method but that didn't work.
How should I do this?

Here is my code:

for index, row in df.iterrows():

```
if row['city']=='mumbai':

    if 5000<= row['rent']<=15000:

        pd.DataFrame.append({'Status': 'Correct'})
```

It shows this error:

TypeError: append() missing 1 required positional argument: 'other'

What procedure should I follow to insert data row by row in a column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with boolean mask created by [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) and comparing with `city`:

```
mask = (df['city']=='mumbai') & df['rent'].between(5000,15000)
df['status'] = np.where(mask, 'Correct', 'Uncorrect')
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'city':['mumbai','mumbai','mumbai', 'a'],
                   'rent':[1000,6000,10000,10000]})
mask = (df['city']=='mumbai') & df['rent'].between(5000,15000)
df['status'] = np.where(mask, 'Correct', 'Flag')
print (df)
     city   rent   status
0  mumbai   1000     Flag
1  mumbai   6000  Correct
2  mumbai  10000  Correct
3       a  10000     Flag
```

Another solution with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
mask = (df['city']=='mumbai') & df['rent'].between(5000,15000)
df['status'] = 'Flag'
df.loc[mask, 'status'] =  'Correct'
print (df)
     city   rent   status
0  mumbai   1000     Flag
1  mumbai   6000  Correct
2  mumbai  10000  Correct
3       a  10000     Flag
```

For write to excel use [`to_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html), if need remove index column add `index=False`:

```
df.to_excel('file.xlsx', index=False)
```

EDIT:

For multiple `mask`s is possible use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'city':['Mumbai','Mumbai','Delhi', 'Delhi', 'Bangalore', 'Bangalore'],
                   'rent':[1000,6000,10000,1000,4000,5000]})
print (df)
        city   rent
0     Mumbai   1000
1     Mumbai   6000
2      Delhi  10000
3      Delhi   1000
4  Bangalore   4000
5  Bangalore   5000
```

---

```
m1 = (df['city']=='Mumbai') & df['rent'].between(5000,15000)
m2 = (df['city']=='Delhi') & df['rent'].between(1000,5000)
m3 = (df['city']=='Bangalore') & df['rent'].between(3000,5000)

m = m1 | m2 | m3
print (m)
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
5     True
dtype: bool

from functools import reduce
mList = [m1,m2,m3]
m = reduce(lambda x,y: x | y, mList)
print (m)
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
5     True
dtype: bool

print (df[m])
        city  rent
1     Mumbai  6000
3      Delhi  1000
4  Bangalore  4000
5  Bangalore  5000
```

Comment: It shows correct result but it doesn't write data in my excel sheet

Comment: It deletes my previous data of sheet. It only insert one column of Status. Please help in this case

Comment: Hmmm, data are different as in df? If original data are overwritten by same, only new column is added, there is some problem? Can you explain more?

Comment: Actually, i have excel file with 50 column and Status is one of them empty column. I want to insert value in this column in my existing file but it deletes all other columns.

Comment: Hmm, it is weird. Because if use `mask = (df['city']=='mumbai') & df['rent'].between(5000,15000)` and `
df['status'] = np.where(mask, 'Correct', 'Flag')` there is no reason for delete anothe columns...

Comment: I have solved the delete problem. Can you please tell me how should I proceed if I want to multi-check for city column. Means I want to enter 'Correct' for a different range of rent if city = Mumbai, Delhi, Bangalore. All have a different range of Rent.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. It is really helpful.

Comment: Glad can help. I always try add some data sample, it is best for understanding problem. And thank you for accepting!